# Find and replace only matching first result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I've written a method to find and replace a string in a bigger string like so:

```
def user_gsubbed_text
  text.include?('##')
    var = text.match(/##\w+/).to_s.tr('##', '')
    text.gsub!(var, document.user.send(var.to_sym)).tr('##', '')
  else
    text
  end
end
```

So that if `##phone` is in the string it will be replaced with the user's phone number. It works fine in the first sense, but given a string like this:

```
"Call me on ##phone or email me at ##email."
```

It replaces only the phone number and not the email address. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any kind of loop. Your code simply finds the first `##foo`, then extracts the variable name, then replaces *that variable* globally. Other `#bar`s are not touched at all.

The easy way is to use the block-form of `gsub!`:

```
def user_gsubbed_text(text)
  text.gsub!(/##(\w+)/) do |match|
    document.user.send($1.to_sym)
  end
end
```

Comment: Should you not remove `|match|` or replace `$1` with `match`?

Comment: Can't replace `$1` with `match`, they have different contents (`$1` is `"email"`, `match` is `"##email"`). I *could* remove `| match |`.

Comment: Thanks. A slight muddle on my part.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you could use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a hash:

```
h = { "##phone"=>"123-456-7899", "##email"=>"me@yahoo.com" } 

str = "Call me on ##phone or email me at ##email."

str.gsub(/\#\#\w+/, h)
  #=> "Call me on 123-456-7899 or email me at me@yahoo.com."
```

or:

```
h.default_proc = proc { |h,k| k }
str.gsub(/\S+/, h)
  #=> "Call me on 123-456-7899 or email me at me@yahoo.com."
```

The latter is a bit more flexible, should you want to add additional key-value pairs to the hash.

Comment: The hash approach didn't make sense in my case, thanks though.